# Listview footer not displaying

Tags: android, android-listview, android-fragments

I have created a dynamic listview with lazy loading. I am trying to show a footer to the listview, so that when the user scrolls to the bottom of the listview, it will show "loading more items" (as a footer)and it will load more item.I have implemented lazy loading. I have set the the footer, but it is not getting displayed on the listview. Please help me out.

Tabfragment class containing listview:

```
package com.example.abe;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.ListFragment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AbsListView;
import android.widget.AbsListView.OnScrollListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
public class Tab1Fragment extends ListFragment {
    ListView lv;
    Activity act = this.getActivity();
    Context ct = this.getActivity();
    XMLGettersSetters data;
    boolean loadingMore = false;
    String abc[] = new String[50];
    static int count = 0;
    final int itemsPerPage = 10;
    static ArrayList<String> myListItems = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> myListItems2;
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter1;

    static int size = 0;
    int position = 0;
    int top = 0;
    static String android_array1[];
    ArrayList<String> myListItems3;

    TabsFragmentActivity t = new TabsFragmentActivity();
    String parsed[] = new String[MainActivity.Sarray1.length];

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity().getBaseContext(),
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, t.myarray);
        ;
        View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_frag1_layout, container,
                false);
        lv = (ListView) root.findViewById(android.R.id.list);
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
        getActivity().setTitle("ABE ST count: " + t.stcount + " items");
        parsed = MainActivity.Sarray1;
        for (int j = 0; j < parsed.length; j++) {
            System.out.println("sax" + parsed[j].toString());
        }

        return root;
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        View footerView = ((LayoutInflater) this.getActivity()
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)).inflate(
                R.layout.listfooter, null, false);
        lv.addFooterView(footerView);

        getListView().setOnScrollListener(new OnScrollListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem,
                    int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
                System.out.println(abc.length);
                System.out.println(count);
                System.out.println("First" + firstVisibleItem);
                System.out.println("Vis" + visibleItemCount);
                position = firstVisibleItem;
                View v = lv.getChildAt(0);
                top = (v == null) ? 0 : v.getTop();
                int lastInScreen = firstVisibleItem + visibleItemCount;
                System.out.println("Last" + lastInScreen);
                System.out.println("Total" + totalItemCount);
                if ((lastInScreen == totalItemCount) && !(loadingMore)) {
                    if (count < size) {
                        try {
                            Thread thread = new Thread(null, loadMoreListItems);
                            thread.start();
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }

                    else if (count != 0) {
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                                "Complete Data", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        int lvcnt = lv.getCount();
                        System.out.println("Adapter Count " + " " + lvcnt);
                        System.out.println("Abe adapter count" + " "
                                + adapter.getCount());
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        if (t.check1 == 0) {
            try {
                Thread thread = new Thread(null, loadMoreListItems);
                thread.start();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    private Runnable loadMoreListItems = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            loadingMore = true;
            t.myarray1 = new ArrayList<String>();
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            }
            size = parsed.length;
            for (int i = 0; i < itemsPerPage; i++) {
                if (count < size) {
                    t.myarray1.add(parsed[count].toString());

                    count = count + 1;
                    System.out.println("Count in run " + " " + count);
                } else {
                    break;
                }
            }
            Log.i("a", "b");
            try {
                getActivity().runOnUiThread(returnRes);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            Log.i("a", "b");
        }
    };
    private Runnable returnRes = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (t.myarray1 != null && t.myarray1.size() > 0) {
                for (int j = 0; j < t.myarray1.size(); j++) {
                    adapter.add(t.myarray1.get(j));

                    // adapter1.add(myListItems3.get(j));

                }
            }
            // setListAdapter(adapter);
            Log.i("a", "b");
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            // lv.setSelection(position);
            lv.setSelectionFromTop(position, top);
            Log.i("a", "b");
            getActivity().setTitle(
                    "ABE ST count: " + String.valueOf(adapter.getCount())
                            + " items");
            t.stcount = adapter.getCount();
            loadingMore = false;
            t.check1 = 1;

        }
    };
}
```

Listfooter xml(Used int tabfragment class): XML for the footer:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:paddingTop="7dip"
android:paddingBottom="7dip"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:gravity="center">

<LinearLayout 
    android:id="@+id/footer_layout" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_gravity="center">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/footer_1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
    android:text="Loading"
    android:textSize="14sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Actually, you have to add FooterView to List before setting Adapter.. Like Below..

```
View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_frag1_layout, container,
                false);
lv = (ListView) root.findViewById(android.R.id.list);
View footerView = ((LayoutInflater) this.getActivity()
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)).inflate(
                R.layout.listfooter, null, false);
lv.addFooterView(footerView);
lv.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: Simple and great - 10x!

Comment: ITs great... (you may set lv.setAdapter(null))

Answer (score 12):

In addition to the accepted answer I wanted to point out that some Android versions want the footer to be added before the adapter is set and some version it doesn't seem to matter.

I have seen in my own applications that on version `4.4.4` it doesn't matter in which order you call `addFooterView` and on version `4.2.2` the footer won't show unless you call `addFooterView` **before** `setAdapter`.  Adding a header should always happen before calling `setAdapter` but adding a footer seems to be less strict but it's useful to know that different versions require a different setup. So it's best just to set the headers before calling `setAdapter` to avoid any weird behavior.

Comment: I second that. Running on 4.2.2 and the footer doesn't show. Funny thing is often we think that the implementation is flawed and look for some other solution. Who says android development is easy.

Comment: adding footer after setting adapter doesn't work for android 4.3 also.